# How to remove the Nautilus overwrite prompt when copying files

Tags: nautilus

I copy files A LOT from one place to another. The dialog box that prompts me to confirm file overwrites slows me down a lot. I have tried to get rid of this but can not find where to configure this. Anybody?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the nautilus source code there is no way to force it to merge+overwrite or just overwrite. The code would have to be modified and recompiled in order to support an option that allowed that.

Let me know if your interested in using a hack I've made, the code is simple, it's just not supported.

Comment: Thanks! Too bad, I really hoped there was an easier way. And yes, I'd be interested in that code!